# C++ atomics and cross-thread visibility

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

AFAIK C++ atomics (`<atomic>`) family provide 3 benefits:

- primitive instructions indivisibility (no dirty reads),
- memory ordering (both, for CPU and compiler) and
- cross-thread visibility/changes propagation.

And I am not sure about the third bullet, thus take a look at the following example.

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic_bool a_flag = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false);
struct Data {
    int x;
    long long y;
    char const* z;
} data;

void thread0()
{
    // due to "release" the data will be written to memory
    // exactly in the following order: x -> y -> z
    data.x = 1;
    data.y = 100;
    data.z = "foo";
    // there can be an arbitrary delay between the write 
    // to any of the members and it's visibility in other 
    // threads (which don't synchronize explicitly)

    // atomic_bool guarantees that the write to the "a_flag"
    // will be clean, thus no other thread will ever read some
    // strange mixture of 4bit + 4bits
    a_flag.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}

void thread1()
{
    while (a_flag.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == false) {};
    // "acquire" on a "released" atomic guarantees that all the writes from 
    // thread0 (thus data members modification) will be visible here
}

void thread2()
{
    while (data.y != 100) {};
    // not "acquiring" the "a_flag" doesn't guarantee that will see all the 
    // memory writes, but when I see the z == 100 I know I can assume that 
    // prior writes have been done due to "release ordering" => assert(x == 1)
}

int main()
{
    thread0(); // concurrently
    thread1(); // concurrently
    thread2(); // concurrently

    // join

    return 0;
}
```

First, please validate my assumptions in code (especially `thread2`).

Second, my questions are:

1. How does the `a_flag` write propagate to other cores?
2. Does the `std::atomic` synchronize the `a_flag` in the writer cache with the other cores cache (using MESI, or anything else), or the propagation is automatic?
3. Assuming that on a particular machine a write to a flag is atomic (think int_32 on x86) AND we don't have any private memory to synchronize (we only have a flag) do we need to use atomics?
4. Taking into consideration most popular CPU architectures (x86, x64, ARM v.whatever, IA-64), is the cross-core visibility (I am now *not* considering reorderings) automatic (but potentially delayed), or you need to issue specific commands to propagate any piece of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Cores themselves don't matter. The question is "how do all cores see the same *memory update* eventually", which is something your hardware does for you (e.g. cache coherency protocols). There is only one memory, so the main concern is caching, which is a private concern of the hardware.
2. That question seems unclear. What matters is the acquire-release pair formed by the load and store of `a_flag`, which is a synchronisation point and causes the effects of `thread0` and `thread1` to appear in a certain order (i.e. everything in `thread0` before the store *happens-before* everything after the loop in `thread1`).
3. Yes, otherwise you wouldn't have synchronisation point.
4. You don't need any "commands" in C++. C++ isn't even aware of the fact that it's running on any particular kind of CPU. You could probably run a C++ program on a Rubik's cube with enough imagination. A C++ *compiler* chooses the necessary instructions to implement the synchronisation behaviour that's described by the C++ memory model, and on x86 that involves issuing instruction lock prefixes and memory fences, as well as not reordering instructions too much. Since x86 has a strongly ordered memory model, the above code should produce minimal additional code compared to the naive, incorrect one without atomics.
5. Having your `thread2` in the code makes the entire program undefined behaviour.

---

Just for fun, and to show that working out what's happening for yourself can be edifying, I compiled the code in three variations. (I added a glbbal `int x` and in `thread1` I added `x = data.y;`).

**Acquire/Release:** (your code)

```
thread0:
    mov DWORD PTR data, 1
    mov DWORD PTR data+4, 100
    mov DWORD PTR data+8, 0
    mov DWORD PTR data+12, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov BYTE PTR a_flag, 1
    ret

thread1:
.L14:
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR a_flag
    test    al, al
    je  .L14
    mov eax, DWORD PTR data+4
    mov DWORD PTR x, eax
    ret
```

**Sequentially consistent:** (remove the explicit ordering)

```
thread0:
    mov eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR data, 1
    mov DWORD PTR data+4, 100
    mov DWORD PTR data+8, 0
    mov DWORD PTR data+12, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xchg    al, BYTE PTR a_flag
    ret

thread1:
.L14:
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR a_flag
    test    al, al
    je  .L14
    mov eax, DWORD PTR data+4
    mov DWORD PTR x, eax
    ret
```

**"Naive":** (just using `bool`)

```
thread0:
    mov DWORD PTR data, 1
    mov DWORD PTR data+4, 100
    mov DWORD PTR data+8, 0
    mov DWORD PTR data+12, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov BYTE PTR a_flag, 1
    ret

thread1:
    cmp BYTE PTR a_flag, 0
    jne .L3
.L4:
    jmp .L4
.L3:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR data+4
    mov DWORD PTR x, eax
    ret
```

As you can see, there's not a big difference. The "incorrect" version actually looks mostly correct, except for missing the load (it uses `cmp` with memory operand). The sequentially consistent version hides its expensiveness in the `xcgh` instruction, which has an implicit lock prefix and doesn't seem to require any explicit fences.